# implicit definition of token in parser warning, when definition in lexer

Tags: antlr4

I get this warning when trying to build the parser using version ANTLR 4.7.2

```
warning(125): CobolParser.g4:1075:20: implicit definition of token END_ACCEPT in parser
```

If I change the accept_statement rule to use END_ADD instead of END_ACCEPT,
the parser builds without warnings.

Would you please explain why I am getting this warning,
since the END_ACCEPT is defined in the lexer?

From CobolLexer.g4:

```
END:                 [Ee][Nn][Dd] ;
END_ACCEPT:          END '-' [Aa][Cc][Cc][Ee][Pp][Tt] ;
END_ADD:             END '-' [Aa][Dd][Dd] ;
```

From CobolParser.g4:

```
options { tokenVocab=CobolLexer; }

accept_statement:   ACCEPT accept_target 
                    from_clause? 
                    on_exception_clause* 
                    END_ACCEPT?;

simple_add:         ADD add_from+ 
                    (TO     add_to+)? 
                    (GIVING add_giving+)? 
                    on_size_error_clause*
                    END_ADD?;
```

Comment: That is odd. Perhaps some old lexer definition file is messing things up? Try deleting all generated files and re-generate the lexer and parser. Else try using the most recent version, which is `4.8-1`.

Comment: I run this cleanup script each time before I rebuild the parser:                                                del .\parser\Cobol*.java
    del .\parser\Cobol*.class
    del .\parser\Cobol*.tokens
    del .\parser\*.class,       I will try the latest version of ANTLR.

Comment: Updated my ANTLR version from 4.7.2 to the latest version 4.8, but I still get the same results (implicit definition warning).

Comment: Could not reproduce it, check my answer. You'll need to edit your question and include enough code/grammar so that someone else can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem turns out to be user error on my part as explained below.

Your comment: *Perhaps some old lexer definition file is messing things up?*
got me to investigating further.

Here are the working directory contents (note the old CobolLexer.tokens file):

```
02/03/2016  04:31 PM    <DIR>          parser
10/22/2020  09:14 AM            38,661 CobolLexer.g4
07/31/2019  09:31 AM             5,427 CobolLexer.tokens
10/22/2020  09:14 AM            87,542 CobolParser.g4
```

Batch file buildParser.bat contents:

```
call cleanupParser
call java -jar %ANTLR_HOME% -o parser CobolLexer.g4
call java -jar %ANTLR_HOME% -o parser CobolParser.g4
javac -Xlint:deprecation -cp .;%ANTLR_HOME% parser\*.java
```

I found that renaming CobolLexer.tokens to CobolLexer.tokens.old solved the problem,
so I then checked for ANTLR options that would help avoid this problem.

ANTLR options information:

```
>java -jar %ANTLR_HOME%
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 4.8
 -o ___              specify output directory where all output is generated
 -lib ___            specify location of grammars, tokens files
 -atn                generate rule augmented transition network diagrams
 -encoding ___       specify grammar file encoding; e.g., euc-jp
 -message-format ___ specify output style for messages in antlr, gnu, vs2005
 -long-messages      show exception details when available for errors and warnings
 -listener           generate parse tree listener (default)
 -no-listener        don't generate parse tree listener
 -visitor            generate parse tree visitor
 -no-visitor         don't generate parse tree visitor (default)
 -package ___        specify a package/namespace for the generated code
 -depend             generate file dependencies
 -D<option>=value    set/override a grammar-level option
 -Werror             treat warnings as errors
 -XdbgST             launch StringTemplate visualizer on generated code
 -XdbgSTWait         wait for STViz to close before continuing
 -Xforce-atn         use the ATN simulator for all predictions
 -Xlog               dump lots of logging info to antlr-timestamp.log
 -Xexact-output-dir  all output goes into -o dir regardless of paths/package
```

The -lib option was exactly what I was looking for, so
here is a new version of buildParser.bat using -lib option
that fixes the problem I was having:

```
call cleanupParser
call java -jar %ANTLR_HOME% -o parser CobolLexer.g4
call java -jar %ANTLR_HOME% -o parser -lib parser CobolParser.g4
javac -Xlint:deprecation -cp .;%ANTLR_HOME% parser\*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

ANTLR_JAR="antlr-4.8-complete.jar"
ANTLR_URL="https://www.antlr.org/download/$ANTLR_JAR"

# Download the ANTLR JAR (if not present)
if [ ! -f "$ANTLR_JAR" ]; then
    wget "$ANTLR_URL"
fi


# Create the lexer grammar
echo "lexer grammar CobolLexer;

ACCEPT:              [Aa][Cc][Cc][Ee][Pp][Tt];
ADD:                 [Aa][Dd][Dd];
TO:                  [Tt][Oo];
END:                 [Ee][Nn][Dd];
GIVING:              [Gg][Ii][Vv][Ii][Nn][Gg];
END_ACCEPT:          END '-' [Aa][Cc][Cc][Ee][Pp][Tt];
END_ADD:             END '-' [Aa][Dd][Dd];
ANY:                 .;" > CobolLexer.g4

# Create the parser gramar
echo "parser grammar CobolParser;

options { tokenVocab=CobolLexer; }

accept_statement:   ACCEPT accept_target
                    from_clause?
                    on_exception_clause*
                    END_ACCEPT?;

simple_add:         ADD add_from+
                    (TO     add_to+)?
                    (GIVING add_giving+)?
                    on_size_error_clause*
                    END_ADD?;

accept_target:        ANY;
from_clause:          ANY;
on_exception_clause:  ANY;
add_from:             ANY;
add_to:               ANY;
add_giving:           ANY;
on_size_error_clause: ANY;" > CobolParser.g4

# Generate lexer and parser classes
java -cp "$ANTLR_JAR" org.antlr.v4.Tool *.g4

echo "Done!"
```

When I run the script above, no warning is printed to my console.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem and I solved it just deleting old .token-files